# How do I create a Google-Play-Edition Android Emulator with Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, android-8.0-oreo

I recently got an update to Android Studio Preview 3 Beta 2 called "Google Play Intel x86 Atom System Image" which seems like it *should* be the long-rumored Android Emulator with the Google Play app on it, for testing upgrades and such (Announced this year at Google I/O).

After Downloading, I can see the image as installed when I look at the SDK Manager GUI:

[image]

But when I go the AVD Manager to try and create an AVD with this image, it doesn't seem to be there, either in the "Recommended" section:

[image]

Or in the x86 section:

[image]

So, what gives?  I have the image, but I can't create an AVD with it?

Comment: Seems like the only way to create this avd is by using the avdmanager from the command line:

avdmanager create avd -n playstore -k "system-images;android-26;google_apis_playstore;x86"

After that it will show up in the AVD Manager GUI and start.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The Beta 4 of Android Studio 3 Preview has the ability to create Google-Play enabled emulators for the Nexus 5 and Nexus 5x